# Rails character encoding error: incomplete "\x00" on UTF-16LE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, character-encoding, railstutorial.org

I am following the Ruby on Rails Tutorial (http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/a-demo-app#sec-modeling_demo_users) and successfully completed exercises up to section 2.2.1.

Now experiencing a character encoding issue when I attempt to load any of the User resources (such as localhost:3000/users and localhost:3000/user/new) created in 2.2.1, which is basically out-of-the-box code generated with:

> C:\Users\Dennis\rails_projects\demo_app> rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string

My environment:

- Windows 7 64-bit
- ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20) [i386-mingw32]
- Rails 3.2.9

Rails returns an error page beginning with:

> Encoding::InvalidByteSequenceError in Users#index
>
> Showing C:/Users/Dennis/rails_projects/demo_app/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #6 raised:
>
> ```
> incomplete "\x00" on UTF-16LE
>   (in C:/Users/Dennis/rails_projects/demo_app/app/assets/javascripts/users.js.coffee)
> ```
>
> Extracted source (around line #6):
>
> ```
> 3: <head>
> 4:   <title>DemoApp</title>
> 5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
> 6:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
> 7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
> 8: </head>
> 9: <body>
> ```

Contents of users.js.coffee:

```
# Place all the behaviors and hooks related to the matching controller here.
# All this logic will automatically be available in application.js.
# You can use CoffeeScript in this file: http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/
```

Contents of application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>DemoApp</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

Contents of index.html.erb:

```
<h1>Listing users</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= user.name %></td>
    <td><%= user.email %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', user %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(user) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br />

<%= link_to 'New User', new_user_path %>
```

Comment: please show your `users.js.coffee`

Comment: Updated to show users.js.coffee, application.html.erb, and index.html.erb.

Comment: check in your `Gemfile`, if you have any gem called `execjs`, change its version, ex, add this `gem "execjs", "1.4.0"` to your Gemfile and run `bundle install` to install gem. Then run app again to check if it work. If you don't have that gem, try rename `users.js.coffee` to `users.js` and run again.

Comment: Thank you! Renaming users.js.coffee to users.js worked. The Gemfile did not contain execjs, though I did try adding execjs with a version, but no good outcome.  What was going wrong?  And does this disable CoffeeScript?

Comment: I think it has some conflicts with coffee script on windows. Yes, this is means you only can write javascript code in `users.js`. I posted answer, please accept my answer, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Renaming `users.js.coffee` to `users.js` will work.